# Using mergExt mergBLE on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, livecode

I've been using the excellent mergBLE succesfully on iOS; but I want to use it on desktop (OS X) as well. The package includes a .bundle as well as .lcext; but the instructions concentrate on iOS.  I've got the bundle theoretically loading (per `the externalpackages of stack "Home"`) in LC 6.6.2 (but not in LC 7.1, probably a separate problem). But using the mergBLEInitialize command, in the IDE on OS X, throws a "can't find handler" error.

Answer (score 0):

Red herring.  The problem is that I was running this on MacOS X 10.8.5; mergBLE requires a newer version of CoreBluetooth than is included in that version of OS X.  So it doesn't load properly - LC notes that it loaded it - hence the presence in "the externals" but doesn't report the fact that it didn't complete loading.  I found this by looking at the Console while LC launched - which reported the failure to load the CoreBluetooth library referenced from mergBLE.

Comment: Glad you sorted that out. Yes, 10.9 and a Mac that supports BLE

Comment: Thanks Monte.  Unfortunately although it's loading on a 10.9 machine, and the mergBLE functions appear to work and don't return errors, the stack that works fine on iOS doesn't appear to be communicating on OS X - it's as if the radio isn't doing what the software says. This is on a mac running 10.9, with older built-in BT hardware but using an external dongle (and BT Explorer to switch to it), which does work with an app written in objective C which I'm trying to replace with a LiveCode one.  I'm updating my main mac from 10.8 to 10.10, and will see - if you have any top tips though...?

Comment: Hmm... not sure if it is something unique to your setup or not